# How to know if the user is online providing only the username/nick/participant but not the whole JID (Ejabberd)

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, erlang-ports

I am customising module `mod_muc_room` and I would like to add a function that knows if the user is online but only providing the username. In the module I can find the function `is_user_online`:

```
is_user_online(JID, StateData) ->

LJID = jlib:jid_tolower(JID),

?DICT:is_key(LJID, StateData#state.users).
```

I understand I have to provide username, server, and resource. LJID, would be resulting to something like `{"user", "myserver.com, "someid"}`

I would like add a function that returns the same but providing only the "user" something like

```
User = "user",

is_member_online(User, StateData) ->

?DICT:is_key(User, StateData#state.users).
```

Can I have some advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the list of hosts:

`ejabberd_config:get_global_option(hosts)`

Then use this to check if a user is online:

`ejabberd_sm:get_user_resources(User, Host)`

This will return an empty array if the user is offline.